# Google app engine persists silently fail after first persist

Tags: java, google-app-engine, web-applications, jdo

I have a servlet that is saving code people upload. They can upload multiple code files whose keys are then saved in a code collection. Everything works for exactly one request. After the first request the Code JDO class silently fails to be persisted. Silently as in there is not a single exception anywhere in the app, even using transactions it thinks the tx is closed and commited.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    List<Key> uploadedCodeKeys = new ArrayList<Key>();
    List<Code> uploadedCode = new ArrayList<Code>();
    if(req.getParameterValues("code") == null) {
        resp.sendRedirect("/");
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < req.getParameterValues("code").length; i++) {
        String pastedCode;
        String language;
        String fileName;
        try {
            language = req.getParameterValues("language")[i];
            pastedCode = req.getParameterValues("code")[i];
            fileName = req.getParameterValues("filename")[i];
            if(pastedCode == null || pastedCode.equals("")) {
                pastedCode = "";
            }
            if(language == null) {
                language = "Plain Text";
            }
            if(fileName == null) {
                fileName = "Untitled";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        Code code = new Code(pastedCode, language);
        code.setFileName(fileName);
        uploadedCodeKeys.add(code.getKey());
        uploadedCode.add(code);
    }
    PersistenceManager pm = GAEModel.get().getPersistenceManager();
    Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();
    long id = 0;
    try {
        tx.begin();
        log.info("Attempting to save " + uploadedCode.size() + " files");
        pm.makePersistentAll(uploadedCode);
        tx.commit();
            if(tx.isActive()) {
            log.severe("Failed to save code files!");
            tx.rollback();
            pm.close();
            return;
        }
        CodeCollection cc = new CodeCollection(uploadedCodeKeys);
        pm.makePersistent(cc);
        id = cc.getKey().getId();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to save files!", e);
    } finally {
        pm.close();
    }
```

I'm assigning code a string hash or something, its not a duplicate. I've tried nearly every variation that last few lines that persist that I can think of. The codecollection gets stored everytime with the id's of the nonpersisted code files.

Thanks

Also here are logs from a commit that fails on DEBUG level:

ms=115 cpu_ms=168 api_cpu_ms=98 cpm_usd=0.004754
I 2011-05-24 20:54:17.424
com.mikehershey.paste.server.URLDispatcher doFilter: loading pageUpload
I 2011-05-24 20:54:17.428
org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl close: Outstanding nontx update being committed to datastore
I 2011-05-24 20:54:17.482
org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl close: Outstanding nontx update being committed to datastore

Heres a log that does commit (the first one of an instance always works):
http://pastebin.com/xW6xbfzK

If I put both commits in a tx Code is never persisted even the first time:

```
PersistenceManager pm = GAEModel.get().getPersistenceManager();
    Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();
    try {
        tx.begin();
        log.info("saving code file!");
        pm.makePersistentAll(uploadedCode);
        tx.commit();
    } finally {
        pm.close();
    }
    pm = GAEModel.get().getPersistenceManager();
    tx = pm.currentTransaction();
    try {
        tx.begin();
        CodeCollection cc = new CodeCollection(uploadedCodeKeys);
        pm.makePersistent(cc);
        id = cc.getKey().getId();
        tx.commit();
    } finally {
        pm.close();
    }
```

The above never saves the List(Code) but always saves the CodeCOllection.
When I comment out the tranactions CodeCollection is still always saved, however List(code) is only saved for the first request to an instance. All subsequent requests fail to persist code (silenty)

```
PersistenceManager pm = GAEModel.get().getPersistenceManager();
    //Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();
    try {
        //tx.begin();
        log.info("saving code file!");
        pm.makePersistentAll(uploadedCode);
        //tx.commit();
    } finally {
        pm.close();
    }
    pm = GAEModel.get().getPersistenceManager();
    //tx = pm.currentTransaction();
    try {
        //tx.begin();
        CodeCollection cc = new CodeCollection(uploadedCodeKeys);
        pm.makePersistent(cc);
        id = cc.getKey().getId();
        //tx.commit();
    } finally {
        pm.close();
    }
```

Comment: That's why you have a log ;-) at DEBUG level

Comment: Negative. heres all logs from appspot.com (added to post) they didn't fit here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App engine defaults things to Persistent if no annotation is specified. I had a field in CodeCollection that was used to cache a list of Code, app engine was trying to persist this and it was freaking out. Added a @notpersistent cleared everything up.

Comment: Actually JDO and JPA have defaults for whether something is persistent, not GAE/J. Their docs are totally misleading in that they imply you have to specify @Persistent on everything.

Answer (score 1):

your first persist is in a txn, and your second is not. The second will likely not run with that version of DataNucleus that GAE/J uses (i.e ancient). Put it in a txn, or run a txn after it (tx.begin(); tx.commit();) for the remaining updates to be flushed.

Comment: Interestingly the second commit (codecollection) always runs. It is the first one in tx that doesnt work. I've updated my original post with more information.